# Add Unique Phone Number to Parse Sign Up

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, unique

I am using Parse to create user profiles. I have implemented user login and user sign up fields programmatically through the method below:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    login.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton |      PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten;
    login.delegate = self;
    login.signUpController.delegate = self;
    login.signUpController.fields = PFSignUpFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFSignUpFieldsAdditional | PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton;

    UIColor *color = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    login.signUpController.signUpView.additionalField.attributedPlaceholder =    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Phone Number" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];

    if([PFUser currentUser])
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
        if(!TimerOn)
        {
            CountNumber = 4;
            Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector: @selector(TimerCount) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
            TimerOn = true;
            pictureButton.hidden = false;
            TimerDisplay.hidden=false;
            friendButton.hidden=false;
        }
    } else
    {
        [self presentViewController:login animated: YES completion: nil];
    }
}
```

As you can see I have added an additional sign up field called phone number. I would like to make sure that each user has a unique phone number. While Parse checks that the user has a unique username and unique email address before adding the user to the PFUser class, it does not check for uniqueness in other fields. I have tried to get around this through the code below. However, this produces the error message of "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'User cannot be deleted unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp'". This makes sense because in the code below I am searching for a user who has not yet been registered.

```
-(void) signUpViewController: (PFSignUpViewController *) signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKey:@"additional" equalTo: signUpController.signUpView.additionalField.text];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         //If the phone number exists in the database then do the following
         {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Phone Number Error" message:@"Your digits are already in the system, Homie!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
             [alert show];
             tempCurrentUser = user;
             NSLog(@"%@", tempCurrentUser.objectId);
         } else
         {
             //Start timer and do everything
             if(!TimerOn)
             {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
                 CountNumber = 4;
                 Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector: @selector(TimerCount) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
                 TimerOn = true;
                 pictureButton.hidden = false;
                 TimerDisplay.hidden=false;
                 friendButton.hidden=false;
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

One way I have tried to solve this is by using the following code. However when I do I receive the following warning: "Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug."

```
- (BOOL)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController shouldBeginSignUp:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [query whereKey:@"additional" equalTo: signUpController.signUpView.additionalField.text];
    PFObject *object = [query getFirstObject];
    //If the phone number exists in the database then do the following
    if (!object)
    {
        return true;
        NSLog(@"The number is unique");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"the number is not unique");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Phone Number Error" message:@"Your digits are already in the system, Homie!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"%li", (unsigned long)requestArray.count);
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: where are you trying to delete the user which gives this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a query to check the uniqueness of the phoneNumber before you make the account. So instead of checking after the account is made, run a query like this before your proceed to signup:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"phoneNumber" equalTo:phoneNumber];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {
        PFUser *user = (PFUser *)object;
        //This phone number already exists!!!

        else {
            //This phone number doesn't exist. Proceed to registration.
        }
    }
    else {
        //This phone number doesn't exist. Proceed to registration.
    }
}];
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I was trying to do before. When am I supposed to run that query? Right now, if I run that query when the user hits the sign up button I will be able to show that the phone number already exists, however, the user will still be added to the database. How do I make sure that registration is not entered if the number exists?

Comment: There is a delegate method called `- (BOOL)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController shouldBeginSignUp:(NSDictionary *)info` that capture the event prior to sign up. It requires you to return a BOOL to see if signup should proceed. Unfortunately, if you do `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` you won't be able to return the Boolean in time. So either do the `getFirstObject` in the foreground, or call the creation of the account from within the block manually. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: thanks. I am implementing that method with getFirstObject in the foreground. However I am getting the error:" Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug." I have added my code to show you exactly what method I am implementing.

Comment: That warning is normal for running a foreground parse method. While it's not the most ideal method, it won't cause any problems unless there is no internet.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not see it in your code, it sounds like you are registering the user then checking the phone number field. If the number is found then you delete the user account.

There are a few options.

1. You can add cloud code for a before save that will check the phone number field.
2. You can check the phone number field BEFORE you save the account. (approach I would take).

If you choose #2 you will query parse for the phone number field. If you don't find the phone number in the database then you continue with the registration process. If you do, you alert the user and do not continue with the registration process.

You will want to override the `shouldBeginSignUp` https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate.html#//api/name/signUpViewController:shouldBeginSignUp:

Comment: How do I interrupt that sign up process programmatically so that I first perform query to see if the phone number exists? Your solution is exactly what I would like to do but not exactly sure what method to implement to do so.

Comment: @user3768643 You need to override the `shouldBeginSignup` in the PFSignUpController. https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate.html#//api/name/signUpViewController:shouldBeginSignUp: do your checking inside that method and return either YES or NO.